# Show that $\operatorname{Cl}(A) \times \operatorname{Cl}(B) = \operatorname{Cl}(A \times B)$ without using idea of closure points

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I've already shown that $\operatorname{Cl}(A \times B)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Cl}(A) \times \operatorname{Cl}(B)$, but I'm not sure how to show the other containment: $\operatorname{Cl}(A) \times \operatorname{Cl}(B)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Cl}(A \times B)$.

I found a very neat proof that uses "closure points" but closure points are not something we have in our repertoire so I don't want to use it.  I want to know if there's a simple way of proving this containment without using closure points.

Here's what I have so far:

I know that $\operatorname{Cl}(A) \times \operatorname{Cl}(B)$ is a closed set from the first containment.  Since it is a closed set, it is contained within its closure... so I basically get that $\operatorname{Cl}(A) \times \operatorname{Cl}(B)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Cl}(A) \times \operatorname{Cl}(B)) = \operatorname{Cl}(A \times B)$.  I think I'm on the right track but obviously this isn't exactly right.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: What is your definition of closure?

Comment: It totally depends on what your definition of closure is.

Comment: According to my notes, the closure of a set A is the smallest closed set containing A, or in other words, the intersection of all closed sets containing A.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Recall the definition of the product topology.  Show that a point outside $\operatorname{Cl}(A \times B)$ is also outside $\operatorname{Cl}(A) \times \operatorname{Cl}(B)$.